# sqlite3 Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

My query attempts to retrieve the sales volumes of a specific product requested by the input from a monthly basis. When i supply the input, the number of bindings supplied in the error is the length of the string of the title variable.

```
title = input("Enter column to search")
import sqlite3

sql = """SELECT SUM(sub.sales) as total_sales,
            strftime("%m-%Y", sub.[orderDate]) as 'month-year'
        FROM 
            (SELECT [orderDate], Espresso AS sales, 'Espresso' as item
            FROM groupedSales

            UNION ALL 

            SELECT [orderDate], Espresso AS sales, 'Espresso' as item
            FROM groupedSales

            UNION ALL 

            SELECT [orderDate], Mocha AS sales, 'Mocha' as item
            FROM groupedSales

            ) AS sub
        WHERE sub.[item] = ?
        GROUP BY strftime("%m-%Y", sub.[orderDate])
        """

conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute(sql, title,).fetchall()

for values in aggregateIndividuals:
    print(values)
```

Enter column to searchEspresso

```
File "C:/Users/stecd/Desktop/NEA - Copy/UNIONtest.py", line 27, in <module>
    aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute(sql, title,).fetchall()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 8 supplied.
```

Comment: Try:   `aggregateIndividuals = cur.execute(sql, (title,)).fetchall()`

Comment: Your SQL syntax looks like SQL Server or MS Access.  Why are you using square bracket notation?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sqlite accepts that and MySQL-style backticks as well as the usual double quotes for quoting identifiers. No quoting needed in this query, of course.

Comment: @Shawn It sounds like SQLite is trying to please everyone.  Sort of like a politician :-)

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve this: 'SELECT [orderDate], (?) AS sales, '(?' as item FROM groupedSales' without having to specify so many selects for each product, and just pass the inputted value in?